# how to change charts colors in slate admin?

Tags: jquery, css, visualize

I'm using slate admin and I display some charts and it works pretty well but I would like to change colors of these charts (they aren't different enough).

Where are these colors configured? Is it possible to do it with a javascript call?

Thanks!

Comment: Slate admin is a template to make an administration panel. http://themeforest.net/item/slate-admin/133854

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be a commercial product. Have you tried contacting the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Locate the file

```
js/slate/slate.js
```

and change the line

```
var chartColors = ['#be1e2d','#0CC912','#92d5ea','#ee8310','#8d10ee','#5a3b16','#26a4ed','#f45a90','#e9e744'];
```

with the colors you want :)